# How to get key,value from the second object based on the key of the first object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm facing a small issue in forming an array of objects

```
    var json1 = [{
    "PRODUCT_ID": "P02",
    "QUANTITY": 2
},  {
    "PRODUCT_ID": "P01",
    "QUANTITY": 61
}]


var json2 = [{
    "PRODUCT_ID": "P01",
    "NAME": "PEN"
},{
    "PRODUCT_ID": "P02",
    "NAME": "Pencil"
}]
```

Now I need to form the object like below.

```
var finalJSON = [{
    "PRODUCT_ID": "P01",
    "NAME": "PEN",
    "QUANTITY": 61
},{
    "PRODUCT_ID": "P02",
    "NAME": "Pencil",
    "QUANTITY": 2
}]
```

Here in this example I just given only 2 objects in array. But in real time there will be some thousands of objects where I need to get the `NAME` field. I did that using loops. But the complier performance will get reduced in that way. Can someone please help me to achieve in simple way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do as follow,

```js
var json1 = [{
    "PRODUCT_ID": "P02",
    "QUANTITY": 2
},  {
    "PRODUCT_ID": "P01",
    "QUANTITY": 61
}]


var json2 = [{
    "PRODUCT_ID": "P01",
    "NAME": "PEN"
},{
    "PRODUCT_ID": "P02",
    "NAME": "Pencil"
}]

const finalJson = json1.map(j1 => ({...j1, ...json2.filter(j2 => j2["PRODUCT_ID"] === j1["PRODUCT_ID"])[0]}))
console.log(finalJson)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `map` and `Map` collection to have `O(1)` while accessing to the items:

```
let unique = new Map(json2.map(s => [s.PRODUCT_ID, s.NAME]));
let result = json1.map(({PRODUCT_ID, QUANTITY})=> 
    ({PRODUCT_ID, QUANTITY, Name: unique.get(PRODUCT_ID)}));
```

```js
var json1 = [{
    "PRODUCT_ID": "P02",
    "QUANTITY": 2
},  {
    "PRODUCT_ID": "P01",
    "QUANTITY": 61
}]


var json2 = [{
    "PRODUCT_ID": "P01",
    "NAME": "PEN"
},{
    "PRODUCT_ID": "P02",
    "NAME": "Pencil"
}]

let unique = new Map(json2.map(s => [s.PRODUCT_ID, s.NAME]));

let result = json1.map(({PRODUCT_ID, QUANTITY})=> 
    ({PRODUCT_ID, QUANTITY, Name: unique.get(PRODUCT_ID)}));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take a simple object as hash table and iterate the arrays by checking the hash table.

```js
function merge(target, hash = {}) {
    return function (source) {
        for (const item of source) {
            if (!hash[item.PRODUCT_ID]) target.push(hash[item.PRODUCT_ID] = {});
            Object.assign(hash[item.PRODUCT_ID], item);
        }
    };
}

var array1 = [{ PRODUCT_ID: "P02", QUANTITY: 2 }, { PRODUCT_ID: "P01", QUANTITY: 61 }],
    array2 = [{ PRODUCT_ID: "P01", NAME: "PEN" }, { PRODUCT_ID: "P02", NAME: "Pencil" }],
    result = [];

[array1, array2].forEach(merge(result));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the "fastest", that will depend on a lot of things that you have not declared in your question.

That said, the following code runs faster for me (compared to `map`, `merge`, `foreach` options), on Linux, Firefox, on my PC set-up from a few different JavaScript benchmark sites.

A larger test sample (highly possible), real data or anything else could change the results.

```js
var json1 = [{
    "PRODUCT_ID": "P02",
    "QUANTITY": 2
  },{
    "PRODUCT_ID": "P01",
    "QUANTITY": 61
  }];

var json2 = [{
    "PRODUCT_ID": "P01",
    "NAME": "PEN"
  },{
    "PRODUCT_ID": "P02",
    "NAME": "Pencil"
  }];
  
var finalJSON = [];

var i,j, max1 = json1.length, max2 = json2.length;

for(j=0;j<max2;j++) {
  for(i=0;i<max1;i++) {
    if (json1[i]["PRODUCT_ID"] == json2[j]["PRODUCT_ID"]) {
      finalJSON[j] = {
         "PRODUCT_ID":json1[i]["PRODUCT_ID"],
         "NAME":json2[j]["NAME"],
         "QUANTITY":json1[i]["QUANTITY"]
       };
       break;
    }
  }
}
console.log(finalJSON);
```